# UV-mapping. How I can get the correct scale on the x axis?

Tags: texturing, uv

Does someone know how I can get the x-scale of the selceted faces of the UV exactly like the x-scale of the faces below?

[image: Screenshot]

.blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/d23anan0jl1y6mp/U-Bahn_Save_55.blend

Comment: There is uploading images tool available here in the question tools, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for details. Please use it

Comment: Ok, next time Im going to use it

Comment: Edited your post to include the screenshot internally, just have to let it get approved. And what exactly do you mean in this question? Do you want the UV faces on your selected island to match the X-scale of the unselected UV island directly below it in the UV editor?

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean

Comment: You could scale it proportionally and enable vert snapping

Comment: vert snapping doesnt work :c

Comment: I included a link to the blend file, maybe it helps

Comment: For future reference, please use the built-in file upload service https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Alright, fixed it for ya, I'll add an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here you go, I assume this is what you're looking for?

[image]

To achieve what I did in the above picture, you have to mark the seams on the sides of the curve, like so:

[image]

Notice how the edges I selected turns red. The red indicates edges that are UV seams, meaning that when you unwrap your mesh to a UV image, it "cuts" along the red lines.

Then you simply unwrap it with the "Follow Active Quads" option, and there you go!
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: It shouldn't.. Are you following my exact instructions?

Comment: How can I show you a screenshot by using comments?

Comment: You can't except if you're uploading to an external site and post the link here

Comment: It looks like this : http://prntscr.com/g31orn

Comment: But if I open the file I included in my question again and follow your steps, it works fine

Comment: You're doing something wrong then... https://www.dropbox.com/s/zc3y69zksz2ve4w/U-Bahn%20Save%2055.blend?dl=0 this is my dropbox link to the file I worked on. Make sure you download it, I'll delete it in a few days